# Rendering array element dynamically in React Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm working on a React JS app. I'd like to make a selection of a letter among an array of letters, based on title + date. Then the selected letter should be displayed below. This is what I did:

```js
class ReceivedLetters extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedLetterIndex: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.receivedLetters[0]) {
      this.setState({
        selectedLetterIndex: 0
      });
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedLetterIndex: e.target.value });
  }

  getListOfLetters = () => {
    var list = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.receivedLetters.length; i++) {
      list.push(
        <option value={i}>
          {this.props.receivedLetters[i].mailingDate}
          {this.props.receivedLetters[i].title} {i}
        </option>
      );
    }
    return list;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="containerReceivedLetters">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sel1">Select the letter:</label>
          <select onChange={this.handleChange} class="form-control" id="sel1">
            {this.getListOfLetters()}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          my index is = {this.state.selectedLetterIndex} {/*THIS IS WORKING FINE,I CAN SELECT A LETTER AND RENDER ITS INDEX */}
          <br />
          {this.props.receivedLetters[0].letterBody} {/* THIS WORKS (render bodyof letter 0)*/}
          {this.props.receivedLetters[this.state.selectedLetterIndex].letterBody } {/*SO WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING? */}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ReceivedLetters;
```

When I try to render the body of the selected letter, I got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'letterBody' of undefined

Can someone help me understand what the problem is?

Comment: print your receivedLetters array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.state.selectedLetterIndex` should initially be set to `0` not `""`.

Comment: Indeed, it now works. But could you please explain what was the problem with the " " , I don't get it.

Comment: Sure -- `array[""]` isn't a valid way to access an array, since the index has to be an integer, e.g. `array[2]`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is initially, before `this.props.receivedLetters[0]` actually has value, your component is already rendered, so you are getting `this.props.receivedLetters[""].letterBody`, which cause the warning. "" is the default value of your `this.state.selectedLetterIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to null check that state value

```
{this.state.selectedLetterIndex && 
 this.props.receivedLetters[this.state.selectedLetterIndex].letterBody} // SO WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING?
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, this.state.selectedLetterIndex > output= 0 and this.props.receivedLetters[this.state.selectedLetterIndex].letterBody output = nothing. I don't really understand whats happening

Comment: Probably because an empty string is not null. My mistake I thought `selectedLetterIndex` was a number